# fastest way to load multiple count queries

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, query-performance

[image]I have developed a MIS Report in my swing application. Means a table
in which the first column contains date column followed by 7 columns of invoice status like pending for payment, paid, pending for park, post etc..

Just trying to show the EXCEL PIVOT LIKE table report in swing, I have successfully implemented it.

but the problem is: day by day the row count is increasing and I have developed a query like

```
select count(invoice_No) 
from MyTable 
where ClaimStatus='columnHeader' 
AND date='row1stColumn'
```

and it will loop through all rows and column to get desired count and will display it into jtable.

But as I said the row count gets increased day by day and SQL Server table data is also increasing a lot.

So my count query gets lot of time to populate that table

Is there any way to make above query faster?

If anyone wants to see my code I will provide it.

I have implemented my application but because of huge data its taking time to show MIS Report

Please see the picture i have attached which is the output of my code.

And The code is,

1) for distinct dates in 1st column

```
q="Select distinct(Inward_Date_Short) from Inward_Master";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
                ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    inwardDateList.add(rs.getString(1));
                }
```

2) static columns of JTable

```
headers.add("Pending For Digitization");
            headers.add("Pending For Claim Creation");
            headers.add("Resolution - Pending For Claim Creation");
            headers.add("Pending For Approval");
            headers.add("Pending For Parking");
            headers.add("Pending For Posting");
            headers.add("Objection");
            headers.add("Pending For Payment");
            headers.add("Paid");
            headers.add("Rejected");
            headers.add("Outward");
```

3) now this is most important code which i want to make more faster

```
for(int i=0;i<inwardDateList.size();i++)
            {
            Vector varsha=new Vector();

             varsha.add(inwardDateList.get(i).toString());

                for(int c=1;c<headers.size();c++)
                {
                    try(Connection con=dbConnection.dbConnector();)
                    {

                        String q="";
                        q=headers.get(c).toString();
                        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Select COUNT_BIG(Inward_No) from Inward_Master where Inward_Date_Short='"+inwardDateList.get(i).toString()+"' AND Claim_Status='"+q+"'");
                        //PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Select count(Inward_No) from(Select Inward_No from Inward_Master where Inward_Date_Short='"+inwardDateList.get(i).toString()+"' AND Claim_Status='"+q+"') X");

                        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                        rs.next();                      
                        data.add(rs.getInt(1));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                rowdata.add(data);
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean a literal SQL query, or do you mean some code you wrote?  We really need to see relevant code to give you a useful answer.  Please add a [MCVE].

Comment: This sounds like something that can be solved with window functions.

Comment: Please see my updated question with code that i tried and picture of my output

Comment: dear team, please suggest something

Comment: isnt there any way or answer for my query?